# Query to get list active queries in my SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get a list of information of active queries that are running in my SQL Server (in order to kill a few of those queries).

I want a query to get this required information:

```
| query_id (if possible) | query_text | query_start_time | time_elapsed | host_name | user_group | query_status |
```

I am new to SQL Server please suggest....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
    r.session_id,
    r.status,
    r.command,
    r.cpu_time,
    r.total_elapsed_time,
    t.text
from sys.dm_exec_requests as r
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) as t
```

Comment: i want to kill query based on something like query id or identify who exectuted that query. how is that possible ??

Comment: kill @session_id - Terminates a user process that is based on the session ID

Comment: kill @session_id may kill all the queries that is running right ? i want to kill exactly one of the query that is running in that session

Comment: how many queries are running in that process at one given moment of time?

Comment: select p.spid, p.status,p.hostname,p.loginname,p.cpu,r.start_time,t.text
    from sys.dm_exec_request as r,
    master.dbo.sysprocess as p,
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.sql_handel)
    where p.status not in ('sleeping', 'background')
    and r.session_id=p.spid

    kill @spid

Comment: kill @session_id must be fine as u said